# Unable to get values for backup metrics from azure Microsoft.DataProtection/BackupVaults resources using the azure rest api

Tags: azure, metrics, azure-backup-vault

I try to query the metric for DataProtection/BackupVault resource which has two metrics namely `BackupHealthEvents` and `ResourceHealthEvents` using the azure rest api(a sample is given below):
GET [https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/b324c52b-4073-4807-93af-e07d289c093e/resourceGroups/test/providers/Microsoft.DataProtection/BackupVaults/{vaultName}/backupJobs/{jobName}/providers/Microsoft.Insights/metrics?api-version=2018-01-01](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/b324c52b-4073-4807-93af-e07d289c093e/resourceGroups/test/providers/Microsoft.DataProtection/BackupVaults/%7BvaultName%7D/backupJobs/%7BjobName%7D/providers/Microsoft.Insights/metrics?api-version=2018-01-01)
It returns an output, but the metric `BackupHealthEvents` does not return any values even though I have created Backup jobs in the Backup vault

I had seen that not all resources might give metrics by default and we need to manually go and enable it, I saw the 'Diagnostic Setting' option and added it to DataProtection/BackupVault resource where there was an option to add the metric 'Health' for backup vaults as shown in [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-diagnostic-events?tabs=backup-vaults).
I added the destination as my LA workspace and i still do not understand why I don't get any values for the metric, it returns an empty list.
I have probably checked most of the links if any additional configurations are required to get those metrics.

Answer (score 0):

> I added the destination as my LA workspace and i still do not understand why I don't get any values for the metric, it returns an empty list. I have probably checked most of the links if any additional configurations are required to get those metrics.

Here is the `KQL` query to check `Recovery Service Vault` metrics in `Log Analytics Workspace.

```json
    AzureMetrics
    | where ResourceProvider == "MICROSOFT.RECOVERYSERVICES"
    | where MetricName == "BackupHealthEvent"
```

**Result:**

[image]

> Note: Azure Backup currently supports the following metrics.
>
> - **1.Backup Health Events**
> - **2.Restore Health Events** not **Resource Health Events**, Refer the [Ms
>
>   Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/metrics-overview#supported-built-in-metrics)
>   for more details

To check the metric for the `Recovery Service Vault` in `Log Analytics`, ensure that you select the 'Metric' option when enabling the `Diagnostic Setting`, as shown below.

> Note: It may take some time to sync the logs to Log `Analytics Workspace`.

[image]

Reference : [Monitor the health of your backups using Azure Backup Metrics (preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/metrics-overview#view-metrics-in-the-azure-portal)